# Querying collections and relationships using waterline and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, waterline

Using mongodb and waterline, how can I query a collection taking in count a relationship with other?

For example, let's say I have two collections, Employer and Employee. An employer can have one or more employees. How could I get a list of employers based in a property of an employee, like getting the list of employers that have employees with an age above of 25 years.

I know that could be done with two queries specifying the required parameters, but I wonder if that could be done in one query, like mysql using joins.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

No. MongoDB does not support joins so if you need if your data is not embedded in a single collection you will need to use two queries to achieve the result you want